# Deleting of Data on the fly not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to use jquery ajax to delete some data specifically ingredients of a recipe and I am using the CodeIgniter framework but it fails. Here is the parts of my code:

```
$(".delete").live('click',function()
{
 var ri_id = $(this).attr('id');
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this ingredient? Action cannot be undone."))
 { 
  var r_id = "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>";
  alert(ri_id +" " +r_id); 
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/ingredient/delete",
     data: "ri_id="+ri_id +"&r_id=" +r_id,
     success: function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
     },
     failure : alert('fail')
  });
```

Then here is my ingredient.php:

```
class Ingredient extends CI_Controller {

    function delete()
    {
        $data['ri_id']= $this->input->post('ri_id');
        $data['r_id']= $this->input->post('r_id');

        if (!empty($data['id']))
        {
            $this->load->model('ingredient_model', '', TRUE);
            $this->ingredient_model->delete_recipe_ingr($data);
            $this->output->set_output('works');
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->output->set_output('dontwork');
        }
    }

}
```

and my model:

```
  class Recipe_model extends CI_Model
  {
      public function delete_recipe_ingr($data)
      {
          $this->db->where($data);
          $this->db->delete('st_recipe_ingredients');  
      } 
  }
```

Did I miss something or is it my code that is wrong? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the success part doesn't execute, only the failure part. There is no console error. I can see the alert box which says 'fail'.

Comment: I think you mean `error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert(error) }`, there is no `failure` option and saying `failure: alert('fail')` will execute the `alert()` immediately.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. I don't have errors but still the data I am trying to delete does not perform right. :(

Comment: Is my type, url, and data in the .ajax() part right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that `this` isn't what you think it is right here:

```
success: function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
},
```

From the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **context**
>   This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the `context` is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`).

So inside your `success` callback, `this` is pretty much a simple object rather than something in the DOM.

There are two standard solutions. You could save a reference to `this` and use that:

```
var self = this;
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function() {
        $(self).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    },
    // ...
```

or use the `context` option to `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    context: this,
    success: function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    },
    // ...
```

And, of course, fix up the `failure` stuff as discussed in the comments.

Comment: I got it. The row that I will delete would then disappear that it goes to the success part but when I refresh the page. The data are still there. It's that they are just removed on the page and not in the database. Are my parameters in my type, url, and data right? Is there a chance that I could check the things that I pass to the controller? Or is the path I indicated on the url right? Sorry, it's my very first time to do something like this. Please bear with me. :(

Comment: @Jagad: I'm not sure about the PHP side of things, sorry. I updated the tags on your question so hopefully someone will come along and help your sort out the other half of your problem.

Comment: I got it now. :) Thanks. I just need to fix the scripts in my controller and model.

Comment: @Jagad: Cool, glad I could help even without knowing anything about CodeIgniter.